# How can I open an accordion-styled grid on page load using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I’ve got two pages — let’s call them page A and page B.

Page A has 4 links going to page B.

On page B I’ve got an accordion-styled grid — see http://css-tricks.com/examples/InfoGrid/

I’m trying to get it so if I click on one of the links on page A it will open one of the tabs on page B.

Can anyone help me?! Cheers.

Comment: +1 .. i really want to know this ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page A, give each of the links a hash value that will match an ID of each accordion item on page B.

```
<a href='pageB.html#sectionOne'> Section One </a>
<a href='pageB.html#sectionTwo'> Section Two </a>
<a href='pageB.html#sectionThree'> Section Three </a>
```

Then on page B, Give each accordion item that you would click an ID that matches the hash values above.

*(If one of them currently has an ID of "starter", change it to the ID you intend to use.)*

```
<dt id="sectionOne" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 14px; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; ">
   Section One
</dt>
...
<dt id="sectionTwo" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 14px; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; ">
   Section Two
</dt>
...
<dt id="sectionThree" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 14px; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; ">
   Section Three
</dt>
```

Finally, in the infogrid.js file, replace this line:

```
$("#starter").trigger("click");
```

with this:

```
$(window.location.hash).trigger("click");
```

It will get the hash value from the location bar, and use it to trigger the click event on the proper accordion item.

---

**EDIT:**

As noted by **@Tomas Lycken**, you do probably want some default. You can either use the `#starter` ID provided ( then use that in the appropriate link ), or choose your own.

If you wanted `#sectionOne` to be the default, you could do this:

```
$( (window.location.hash || '#sectionOne') ).trigger("click");
```

This will use the hash value if there is one, or `#sectionOne` if not.

If you want to safeguard against invalid hash values, you could do this:

```
var $viewAtPageLoad = $( window.location.hash ).trigger("click");

if(!$viewAtPageLoad.length) {
    $('#sectionOne').trigger("click");
);
```

Comment: +1! =) You should even be able to specify `'#starter'` as the default selector if no hash was given =)

Comment: @Tomas - That's a good point. There should really be a default. I'll update.

Comment: cheers everyone cant believe i didnt think of doing it that way! yes student badge is right!